# Using the "print screen" key on the keyboard as a viable key press in ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses, printscreen

I am using C to write up a program that uses every key on the keyboard for int. In C, I am using `ncurses.h` and am using `cbreak()`. `cbreak()` doesn't work with it. I then used `raw()` which is apparently is supposed to stop all keyboard input.

I am using

```
keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
```

to take all keyboard input, and it still doesn't take print screen as an input value and ignores it

If anyone has answer for this?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.gnu.org/software/guile-ncurses/manual/html_node/Getting-characters-from-the-keyboard.html .  I think you are looking for the `KEY_PRINT` key.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running it in a desktop environment (Gnome, KDE, etc.) the PrintScreen key is usually intercepted by it and the ncurses application will not receive it. You should test your program in a plain virtual console instead outside the desktop environment.